# Does the QGIS Georeferencer have a point prediction function?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, georeferencing, ground-control

When taking GCP using Georeferencing in QGIS,
Is there a point prediction function?

For example, when working on GCP in an ERDAS program, put reference coordinates (ex: 10 coordinates)
After taking the first three GCPs of the geographic reference and reference images, the remaining seven GCP coordinate predictions are shown. So, it is easy to work on GCP by fine-tuning 7 GCPs.

Does QGIS have this function? Can I do GCP work only manually?